# Plotting multiple subplots want one colobar

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am getting multiple colobar for each subplot,i want one for all.

```
for i in range(6):
     plot.subplot(2,3,i)
     im=plot.contourf(xlon[:],xlat[:],rain[i,:,:])
     plot.colorbar(im)
plot.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding the `colorbar` on its own axis. This can be done by manually creating an additional axis and shifting the existing plots as needed using `subplots_adjust()` and `add_axes()` e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=300)
for i in range(1,7):
    # This simply creates some random data to populate with
    a = np.arange(10)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(a, a)
    z = np.random.randint(0, 7, (10, 10))

    plt.subplot(2,3,i)
    im=plt.contourf(x, y, z)

# Tight layout is optional
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.825)
cax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.06, 0.035, 0.91])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
plt.show()
```

The arguments for `add_axes()` in this case are `[left, bottom, width, height]`. This will produce something like

[image: Sample figure with 6 subplots sharing one colorbar]

#### Edit

To remove the inter-plot axis labels, tick marks, etc requires a somewhat non-trivial modification from the above method wherein `plt.subplots()` is used to populate a `2x3` array of subplot objects over which we then iterate. E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

nrows = 2
ncols = 3
# Create the subplot array
fig, (axes) = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(10, 6), 
                           dpi=300, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        a = np.arange(10)
        x, y = np.meshgrid(a, a)
        z = np.random.randint(0, 7, (10, 10))
        im = axes[i][j].contourf(x, y, z)
        # Remove the tick marks but leave the superleft and superbottom alone
        if i != nrows-1:
            if j != 0:
                axes[i][j].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', 
                           left=False, bottom=False, top=False)
            else:
                axes[i][j].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom=False, top=False)
        else:
            if j != 0:
                axes[i][j].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', left=False, top=False)
fig.tight_layout()
# Some additional whitespace adjustment is needed
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.825, hspace=0.025, wspace=0.025)
cax = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.06, 0.035, 0.91])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
plt.show()
```

[image: Modified figure]

Comment: thanks @William it work.

Comment: @MissPriyaKumari be sure to hit the check mark next to the answer if it correctly answers the question

Comment: Thanks next time I will notice this.

Comment: Can u tell me where should I right sharex=True, sharey=True in above code..i trying to set x and y-axis value do not show in between the subplot.

Comment: @MissPriyaKumari That is somewhat non-trivial in this case, please see the edited code above for a solution.

Comment: actually, I want to do in that only if in the above code is not possible then it is difficult for me .... This is code actually my code: I am plotting rainfall data ...where i is time step here..for i in range(1,25):

        plot.subplot(5,5,i)
        #im=plt.contourf(x, y, z)

        im=plot.contourf(xlon[48:],xlat[36:],diffrain[i,36:,48:])

Comment: @MissPriyaKumari You really should accept this answer by clicking the check mark! This will not only give Willliam points for his really good answer, you'll also get some points.

Comment: @scotty1 ...thanks to pointed me

Comment: @William in above code for colobar ..that is not for all subplot colobar ...fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax) this is for last plot only ..i just noticed , please help me..

Comment: The above code is fine, but there is an easier way:
`fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes)`
will place the colorbar to the right of the axes listed in `ax`